# Paredit ignore comments when closing parens

Tags: emacs, formatting, paredit

Often I run into situations like the following while using `paredit`, with the point at the `|` in the following snippet where I want to close the dangling paren, eg.

```
(let ((foo 1)| ; blag
      )
  nil)
```

becomes

```
(let ((foo 1)) ; blag
  nil)
```

after type `)` aka `paredit-close-parenthesis` at the point.

If the comment wasn't on the line, `paredit` would close the paren and remove the space.  Does anyone have a nice way to enable this feature?

Looking at the code, `paredit` appears to catch errors where I could add handlers, so I'm wondering if there is a simple solution out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess overriding it seems to work so far.

```
(defun my-paredit-close-round (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (if arg (paredit-close-round)
    (let ((beg (point)) ;keep comment on same line
          (cmt (paredit-find-comment-on-line)))
      (paredit-move-past-close ?\))
      (and cmt (save-excursion
                 (unless (eq (line-number-at-pos) (line-number-at-pos beg))
                   (goto-char beg))
                 (insert (car cmt)))))))
(advice-add 'paredit-close-round :override #'my-paredit-close-round)
```

However `paredit-backward-barf-sexp` still gets stuck at comments and would need to be overriden as well.